# Linux C Makefile (FFmpeg) undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'

Tags: c, ffmpeg, makefile, libcurl

I did some changes to /libavformat/concat.c in the FFmpeg source.
There I included libcurl.

Internet says I have to add the following code to 'Makefile'.

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS = -lcurl
```

That did not work.
I use this to build FFmpeg:

```
make clean && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 && make -j 4
```

Error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libavformat.a(concat.o): In function `concat_read':
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavformat/concat.c:151: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavformat/concat.c:155: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavformat/concat.c:156: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavformat/concat.c:158: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
```

original Makefile:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/Makefile

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show the build command that is generating that error.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see above. "make clean && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 && make -j 4"

Comment: That's the top level make command not the actual build command that causes the error. The one that causes the error is the one that has gcc in it (or some other compilation step).

Comment: There was an include in the makefile. "common.mak" showing some gcc stuff. Maybe this helps. https://infotomb.com/deo4j.txt

Comment: What Alan Au is asking you to do is post the lines that appear in the output before the error you quoted in your question.

Comment: few lines above + under the quoted error: https://infotomb.com/h6f4y.txt

Comment: The autotools generate `Makefile` from either `Makefile.am` or `Makefile.in` so if you changed the `Makefile` and re-ran the `configure` script it likely removed your changes. Check that they are still there (assuming you need to make them that way). Also adding `V=1` to the main make command line should cause make to output the actual commands being run instead of the "friendly" `LD`/`MAN`/etc. output.

Comment: Here is the "unfriendly" output with previos gcc: http://puu.sh/j9Ulo/ca315cc6a0.png

Answer (score 1):

Use this to configure FFmpeg:

./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl'

Don't mess with the Makefile, FFmpeg's build system isn't quite standard and simple as most typical opensource projects' Makefiles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still got that error. Error with previous gcc commands: http://puu.sh/j9Ulo/ca315cc6a0.png

Comment: After --extra-ldflags='-lcurl', you should see -lcurl as part of the LDFLAGS variable in your config.mak, which would cause it to be added to your linker commandline. However, I'm not seeing it here. Is -lcurl part of your LDFLAGS in config.mak? If not, can you add it there or see why it wasn't added automatically when using --extra-ldflags='-lcurl'?

Comment: That's the LDFLAGS variable in the config.mak: LDFLAGS= -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl  -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample